# Copying files and folders to /var/www/html - inherit permissions of ./html

Tags: permissions, acl, incron

I want to enforce web server security and maintain 750 for folders and 640 for files - even when copying, at all times, under all circumstances.

So far, I've got this working quite well. This is what I did:

`sudo chown -R kilomike ./html` (Set owner to my user, the sole user)

`sudo chgrp -R apache ./html` (set group to apache so it can work)

`sudo chmod g+s ./html` (set the group ID so new files/folders inherit the group)

`sudo setfacl -d -m g::rx ./html` (only allow group to read and execute [should be safe, because file creation using touch and other methods doesn't set execute bit])

`sudo setfacl -d -m o::- ./html` (don't allow other group to even look at it)

This works great for the most part. However, I just KNOW that when I copy a folder or file in to /var/www/html/* I'm going to forget to update its permissions.

What I want is 750 for folders, 640 for files, which is what I attempted to do with setfacl. Despite the fact that technically I set it to 750 (group is r-x and other is ---), I think when I create a FILE it won't (hopefully) apply the execute bit for either the owner or group. This seems to be working, as per `ls -l` or `getfacl`.

My problem is when I copy a folder that was created by some other user, or downloaded from the web, it will preserve the owner, group, and other permissions. I DON'T want that, as I want my /var/www/html folder to have the same permissions for EVERY file and folder inside it.

Does anyone know how to do it? Is the best way to do it with an `incron` job (e.g. change on /var/www/html or any file/folder inside it, then "refresh" permissions for EVERYTHING), or is there a better way?

Comment: Have a look at the `umask` command. It defines how permissions are set when you create new files.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, default ACLs take the place of `umask` if they're set

Comment: @Kevin, how do you copy the files there? Is the issue with `cp -a` or `tar` or some other program that explicitly sets the permissions to what they were on the source?

Comment: @ilkkachu I was just using the nautilus GUI, after unzipping via right click. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is possible with the GUI so if not, a console solution is suitable too.

Comment: If you want that file when copied from the folder X to the folder Y would automatically get predefined permissions, then take a look to [install](https://linux.die.net/man/1/install).